# Print multiple tcl lists in a uniform manner

Tags: tcl

I have a group of lists some with strings, some with numbers and some with both. All these lists have variable lengths. I would like to know what would be the best way to print it to a file so that they all have equal spacing between them.

For example, I use,

```
set numbers {0 1 2 3 4}
set type {dog reallybigbaddog thisisaevenlargersentence cat bird}
set paths {aaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb ccc ddddddddddddddddd  efgh}
puts $fid "NUMBERS\t\tTYPE\tPATHS"
foreach numbersval $numbers typeval $type  pathsval $paths  {
    puts $fid "$numbersval\t\t$typeval\t$pathsval"
}
```

The result was,

```
NUMBERS      TYPE                         PATHS
0            dog       AAA
1            reallybigbaddog       bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
2            thisisaevenlargersentence       ccc 
3            cat       ddddddddddddddddd
4            bird       efgh
```

I Tried using "format" based on one of the suggestions on this site but that resulted in a similar output, I guess we need a way to determining what the longest string is and cant arbitrarily use "\t"? Would appreciate any better suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I'd call out to `column -t` to do the work for me:

```
set all "NUMBERS TYPE PATHS\n"
foreach n $numbers t $type p $paths {
    append all "$n $t $p\n"
}
set formatted [exec column -t << $all]
puts $formatted
```

```
NUMBERS  TYPE                       PATHS
0        dog                        aaa
1        reallybigbaddog            bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
2        thisisaevenlargersentence  ccc
3        cat                        ddddddddddddddddd
4        bird                       efgh
```

---

A pure Tcl way to do this:

```
array set maxl {numbers 0 type 0 paths 0}
foreach l {numbers type paths} {
    foreach e [concat $l [set $l]] {
        if {[set len [string length $e]] > $maxl($l)} {
            set maxl($l) $len
        } 
    } 
} 
puts [format "%-*s %-*s %-*s" $maxl(numbers) NUMBERS $maxl(type) TYPE $maxl(paths) "PATH LISTS"]
foreach n $numbers t $type p $paths {
    puts [format "%-*s %-*s %-*s" $maxl(numbers) $n $maxl(type) $t $maxl(paths) $p] 
}
```

Comment: This assumes none of the array elements contain whitespace

Comment: Thanks Glenn! Worked like a charm.

Comment: Maybe the only constraint to this solution would be that the heading should be single words. For example, I cant have it as "PATH LIST", it becomes two different columns. Correct?

Comment: My addition is quite like the way the `parray` procedure is implemented

Answer (score 2):

For reference, this is how you could do it with `struct::matrix` and `report`:

```
package require struct::matrix
package require report

set nrows 5
set ncols 3
set npads [expr {$ncols + 1}]

struct::matrix m
m add rows $nrows
m add column {0 1 2 3 4}
m add column {dog reallybigbaddog thisisaevenlargersentence cat bird}
m add column {aaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb ccc ddddddddddddddddd  efgh}
m insert row 0 {NUMBERS TYPE PATHS}

report::report r $ncols
r data set [lrepeat $npads \t]
m format 2string r
```

(This uses only a fraction of the formatting power of `report`.) This method can handle values with spaces in them.

Result (there is a tab character to the left of the first column on each row, but it's lost in the formatting here.):

```
NUMBERS TYPE                        PATHS                               
0       dog                         aaa                                 
1       reallybigbaddog             bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb    
2       thisisaevenlargersentence   ccc                                 
3       cat                         ddddddddddddddddd                   
4       bird                        efgh
```

Documentation: [expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm), [lrepeat](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lrepeat.htm), [package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm), [report](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/report/report.html) package, [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [struct::matrix](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/struct/matrix.html) package

Comment: I figured there was something in tcllib for this but I was too lazy to look for it

Comment: Thanks!!! I was unaware of "report" in tcl. I am having problem with using this though, so I am using tcl shell inside of a completely different tool. I get the error ":: m" already exists, unable to create matrix. I am not sure if this is a tool error or tcl shell error. Maybe the tool does not support all tcl libs. I will debug and get to the bottom of it.

Comment: @user2045143: once you've created a matrix object, you need to destroy it (`m destroy`) before you can create another with the same name.